# Waist Measurement with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am pretty much new to OpenCV and I am working on this project to measure the waists of a person. I have a rough work up to where I used [this post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/) from pyimagesearch

In my rough work, I took the front view of the waist, scaled it down and calculated the measurement. The result was scaled back up and squared (to cover for the back view, given that it was only the front view I measured).

I did the same method for the side view but the problem with the side view is that one can't say where the side starts and ends. So this will make the total calculations incorrect.

Another caveat is I have been working on a flat stomach and I have not really thought about how to handle a bigger stomach

This is the image I am currently testing with
[Waist-Uncropped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF1jq.jpg)

Comment: Would the pictures of waists always be the same distance? If so you could just count the pixels across.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: pixels are pixels. you need a *reference* to convert that into physical units. you might even need 3d data (multiple cameras, or a video of the person turning). front and side view might give enough info for an "elliptical" cross-section model. -- to reliably get "waist" points, you might need a DNN that gives you those points.

Comment: @TrevorBlythe Since it will be for different people, it won't always be the same distance

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I do have a reference object. The objective I thought about was to get the full data of the person turning.
I do not know much about elliptical cross-section model, if you can reference it, I won't mind. I will also look into it.